# Reference to non-object array from class

Tags: c++, reference

Let's say my function had array passed in it like this:

```
int someFunction ( SomeClass * const * array, int arr_size ) { }
```

This is array of some structures:

```
struct SomeStruct {
   int value;
   int value2;
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is making a reference inside of object declared in that function:

```
int someFunction ( SomeStruct * const * array, int arr_size )
{
   NewClass newclass (array, arr_size);
}
```

my constructor would look like this:

```
Newclass::NewClass( SomeStruct * const * array, int arr_size )
{
   SomeStruct ** myReference = new SomeStruct * [arr_size];
   for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
   {
      myReference[i] = array[i];
   }

   myReference[0] -> value = 10;
}
```

Now, if I want to print out value of first element in array, I get just zero.

```
int someFunction ( SomeStruct * const * array, int arr_size )
{
   NewClass newclass (array, arr_size);

   cout << array[0] -> value << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Is it even possible to refer to non-object from class? How do I get my reference array to change the source array? I had the reference array in that function as a non object before and everything worked fine. And no, I can't ***just leave it there***.

Comment: No [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), no particular question (_'what I'm doing wrong'_ is too broad/unclear). Edit!!

Comment: @g-makulik No idea what was unclear about my question. Edited it though.

Comment: I can't tell what you are really trying to do. Why create a `NewClass` only to change a value in `array`? But your `NewClass` constructor does not do what you think it does, and what is with the `* const *`?

Comment: What's "* const *" - are you trying to make the const bold?

Comment: @crashmstr It's not the only thing my class is doing. The code is, of course, much more extensive. `* const *` there prevents me to change the order of elements, but allows me to change its contents.

Comment: @Saraph _'It's not the only thing my class is doing'_ That's the reason we're asking for a SSCCE to nail down your problems!

Comment: I've been doing this for a while now... and this is the first time I've seen `* const *`.

Comment: @crashmstr Agreed! It's suspicious, and usually when I try to use this I get compiler errors, for right!

Comment: @crashmstr It's because for that array every index is significant. I'm creating a reference so I can sort it around and actually be able to work with that array. But when it comes to printing its contents, it has to stay in the original order.

Comment: Try to rewrite your code with references instead of pointer. Take arguments by reference or value whenever you can. make references const whenever you can. Use std::vector or std::array.

Comment: @Saraph I'm thinking you could build a class that held the data, and provide access how you wanted instead of all of these pointers and indirection.

Answer (score 0):

When you're allocating the struct pointers in `Newclass::NewClass()`, you're forgetting to actually initialize those pointers to point to the actual structs.

You need:

```
Newclass::NewClass(SomeStruct* const* array, int arr_size)
{
    SomeStruct** myReference = new SomeStruct*[arr_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
        myReference[i] = array[i];
    }
    myReference[0]->value = 10;
}
```

Though I must say I'm confused about all the pointer indirection and why you need it. And you're leaking memory too; you never `delete[] myReference`.

And you should consider using `std::vector` instead of doing all that memory management manually.

Comment: `myReference[i] = &array[i];` is not possible because of conversion from **const** to non-const. Outside of class, it works even without `&`.

Comment: Then declare `myReference` appropriately. The answer is actually showing the real problem you're having.

Comment: @Saraph Oops, it was actually my mistake. Answer updated. Since the `array` parameter is a pointer to pointer, all you need is `myReference[i] = array[i];`.